# Is there an app that can poll developers' machines to see what un-pushed changes they have?

Tags: git

I work in a small team of developers using git for version control.  While I really prefer git to previous version control systems I've used (VSS, TFS, SVN) there is one problem: We can't see what changes a developer has made that they haven't pushed to the remote.

I'm thinking here of un-pushed commits, or changes that are staged or un-staged which have not yet been committed.

While developers *should* always push their commits at least at the end of the day, they're human and sometimes forget, or sometimes are reluctant to commit and push if something isn't finished.  I find when someone is sick or off on holiday and I need to figure out where their project is at, I can't rely on the remote repository to reliably tell me.  I need to access their machine to look at their local repository and their working folder.

Is there any app that automates this process - that polls each developer's machine and lists un-pushed commits, un-staged changes and staged changes in each repository they have on their machine?

[I know we're using a centralized repository model and git is a distributed version control system so isn't designed to have files checked out of a centralized repository.  We could go to a centralized version control system like SVN that reflects our development model but I prefer the flexibility and power of git and am looking for a way around this one problem.]

Comment: In which branch or branches on their machine??? What about stashes? Encourage them to push, but staging and committing changes just so an end of day push can be done as some sort of backup is just wrong.

Comment: It's not about backing up, since each machine is backed up automatically.  It's about visibility: What was that developer working on, how far have they got?  If I'm in the middle of a change at the end of the day I'll just create a temporary branch, "Simon_EOD", and push that to the origin with my half finished changes.  Then, next morning, I can do a soft reset of that branch to reverse the commit.  The other devs know that "Simon_EOD" is a temp branch and shouldn't be checked out, unless I'm off sick and they need to know what I was doing.  Then, at least, they have mu up-to-date changes.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [git remotes](http://gitref.org/remotes/). You could set up remote repositories for all the other developers and track their local branches.

Comment: Useful idea, I hadn't thought of setting up remotes for the other devs' repositories.  While that would be useful for me personally I don't think it would solve the general problem of change visibility.  Each developer could set up remotes for each of the other developers but it seems like a lot of work (especially since we each have about 10-15 different repositories and can work on 3 or 4 of those in a day).  I'm still hoping for a more universal solution (app that crawls each dev's machine checking on the status of each of their repositories).

Comment: It seems you only need to run 'git status' in each working directory of each machine. It is quite easy to do with a simple bash script (assuming a unix-like system). The actual implementation would depend on how you would find the working directories. Would you force a directory structure policy on everyone? Can you afford to search for working directories (essentially searching for '.git/' directories)? etc.

Comment: Everyone has their working directories under a directory called "Working" on their machines, since that is the main folder that is backed up each night.  Under that root Working directory they can have any directory structure they like (eg some group working directories by customer, others don't group them at all).  Thanks for the idea of the script running "git status", it wouldn't be difficult to search under the Working directory for directories containing a ".git" sub-directory.